# Alternatives to Python and Perl for scripting on linux servers

Tags: python, scripting, perl

Are there any modern scripting alternatives to Python and Perl on linux servers? I like Python, but I'm not fond of the indentation way of structuring code. In that regards, Perl is way better. However, Perl does seem to have lost the momentum it once had. I'm thus looking for alternative (and modern) scripting languages, that won't make me look like a dinosaur at work.

Comment: Python does seem to be the major one, sometimes with an assist from TCL/TK. If you don't have a visceral revulsion to Microsoft, PowerShell is now available for Linux as well.

Comment: With that raw definition, that would get you quite a list (PHP, Ruby, Lua, Shell, …) Dinosaur-size :) So could you please be more specific, e.g. of the features needed?

Comment: Honestly, when you say "not fond of the indentation way of structuring code", I am imagining someone who *doesn't like to indent their code* and as such, that sounds much, *much*, **much** worse than using an out-of-fashion scripting language.

Comment: There is no scripting language with the "momentum [Perl] once had". Scripting is pretty much a Solved Problem, with several good existing solutions, so there's nothing hot and new. Perl is still a perfectly good choice *for scripting* (but not as widely accepted for general-purpose application development). So if you're happy with Perl, use Perl. Or, if your company has an official preferred language, then use that.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've noted PowerShell, Ruby, etc as potential new candidates to my portefolio, in addition to Python and Perl. @john, just to be clear: I always indent my code, I just haven't made friends with Python indentation - for example, I find it unecessary coumbersome to copy and paste code.

Comment: Then maybe you should be looking at what editor you're using, or learning how to use it better. If you really do indent your code, then whether it's Python or Perl, you'd have exactly the same "problem" with copying and pasting.